# ExactTarget fields to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign

Right now, ExactTarget pushes the 'Bounce Date' to Salesforce, which I use as a filter on a report to remove bounced emails. However, this filters out soft bounces as well - something which I do not wish to do. I want to specifically send data from ExactTarget to Salesforce about the type of bounce.

Can I create a field in ExactTarget and map it back to a custom field in Salesforce, and if so, how? I've tried browsing through the documentation and I know I can do the converse, but I didn't see anything for mapping ET fields to SF.

Comment: What version of the integration are you using? I believe V5 does push back bounce type.